# axios POST request works in nodejs but not in react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, post, axios, http-status-code-400

```
axios
  .post(url, form, {
   headers: {
     Cookie: "key1=" + value1 + "; " + "key2=" + value2,
     Referer: value3,
     "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
   },
   transformRequest: (formData) => formData,
 })
 .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
 .catch((error) => console.log(error.response.data));
```

When I use this post request in react native it responds with a 400 status code. Using The same exact code in nodejs, it responds with a 200 status code. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upload a file, then I'd recommend staying away from axios because it doesn't work well for file uploads in react-native environment.

In fact, I'd recommend checking out react-native-blob-util (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blob-util#user-content-multipartform-data-example--post-form-data-with-file-and-data)

If you are not trying to upload the file, then it'd be difficult to figure out what exactly is going on without looking at the logs.